# Can we change firefox profile settings via Selenium in flight?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-profile

I'm using Python 2.7 with Selenium 3.0.1. I'm using Firefox and setting the profile as below:

```
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
```

This works but I have need to download a file on a page to one folder on the machine then download a different file to a different folder.

I can move the file with python if need be but...

**Is there a way to modify the firefox profile to change the download directory in flight?**